# Rooting an RCA, RCT6303W87M7 Android 6.0 Tablet

Tags: applications

This Tablet is sold as "Viking" at Walmart. I want to root it
Without a PC and then find a program that will reveal username
And password for local Wi-Fi users to share their internet.
That's the goal, but I cannot seem to find any common apps that
Will root this tablet. I may be neglecting to turn some tablet
Selection switch on or off. I need someone to tell me the process
Step by step. I'm a BASIC user. Thanks, Bill.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same tablet and I tried all the root apps and nothing worked only one that gave me 75% it's called (one-click root) but it's not the same as the one holding the same name it's different you can try it who knows might work for you you can find it at the aptoide site